# Auditd - track commands (regular and sudo) of a given UID

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, auditd

I have some `auditd` rules like:

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -F euid=1002 -k mytag
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -F euid=1002 -k mytag

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -F euid=1003 -k mytag
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -F euid=1003 -k mytag
```

Which is working fine, but I want to also track the `sudo` commands run
by these users, so I added

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -F euid=0 -k mytag
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -F euid=0 -k mytag
```

But the `sudo` commands do not seem to be tagged with the key. Is there anything
wrong with specifying both these set of commands. Does the order of these rules
matter?

### Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that the commands were logged without the tag, or that the commands were not logged? What other audit rules do you have?

Comment: I did see the logs but they didn't have the tag. I have to mention that I have audisp also enabled.